# Http Server speeds

Tags: java, httpurlconnection, httpserver

I have an application where I am doing multiple requests to a server, via HTTP requests. I am trying to bench mark the response. I don't know what to expect in terms of speeds. 
I have written this sample program to test the same.. What are the speeds I should expect out of this program? Am getting around 4000 requests per second which I feel is QUITE less. Kindly help.

**HTTPClient:**

```
package my.service;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.Date;

public class TestClient {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        Date date = new Date();

        for ( int i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
            URL url = new URL( "http://192.168.5.116:9999/testSpeed" );
            HttpURLConnection conn = ( HttpURLConnection ) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod( "POST" );
            conn.setRequestProperty( "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" );

            conn.setUseCaches( false );
            conn.setDoInput( true );
            conn.setDoOutput( true );

            conn.connect();

            InputStream stream = conn.getInputStream();
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1];
            while ( stream.read( b ) != -1 ) {
                bos.write( b );
            }

            byte[] byteArray = bos.toByteArray();
            String response = new String( byteArray );
            if ( Integer.parseInt( response ) % 1000 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println( "Response from server is --> " + response );
            }
        }

        Date d1 = new Date();
        System.out.println( d1.getTime() - date.getTime() );
    }
```

}

**HTTPServer:**

```
package my.service;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpExchange;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpHandler;
import com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer;

public class TestServer {

    public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
        HttpServer server = HttpServer.create( new InetSocketAddress( 9999 ), 0 );

        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool( 10 );
        server.setExecutor( executorService );

        server.createContext( "/testSpeed", getHandler() );
        server.start();
    }

    private static HttpHandler getHandler() {
        return new TestHandler();
    }

    private static class TestHandler implements HttpHandler {

        int i = 0;

        @Override
        public void handle( HttpExchange request ) throws IOException {
            i++;
            if ( i % 1000 == 0 ) {
                System.out.println( "Number of requests received --> " + i );
            }

            String response = i + "";
            request.sendResponseHeaders( 200, response.getBytes().length );

            OutputStream os = request.getResponseBody();
            os.write( response.getBytes() );
            os.close();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Wrong approach.  A basic tester like this suffers from a number of flaws such as unoptimized thread pool management, and improper simulation of the actual business logic.  Instead, you need to ask what kind of load the application is expected to handle, and determine if your app will meet that requirement ... if not, where is the time being taken and how to address the deficiency.

Comment: Optimizations like? Business logic is very simple., which I dont think it os a problem. How to optimize thread pool?

Comment: I don't know.  This example is far too simple to actually provide any valuable insight.  Reach out to me on other channels if you want consulting services.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, almost all application servers uses fixed size thread pool. That approach is good but as you know this response is too simple. In some situation you need to go database and wait for response.
In that case you can not simulate exact response time.

Also your first concern is not a speed of response. You can configure thread pool size for application servers.(Configurable). Also if the traffic is too much to handle then you need to open two or more server.(Maybe load balancer can be used.).

In my opinion you need to consider this situation after the product is alive but you need to implement code for more than one server.